# How to set property of a pushed object within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an object.

```
{
    "header": [{        
        "items": []
    }]
}

var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"header":[{"items":[]}]}');
```

I push an object to the items

```
var align = jQuery.parseJSON('{"align":""}');
jObj["header"][0].items.push(align);
jObj["header"][0].items.push(align);
```

I set the values

```
jObj["header"][0].items[0].align = "right";
jObj["header"][0].items[1].align = "left";

console.log(JSON.stringify(jObj));
```

I get the same value for both aligns, how do I set the values?

**Output**

> {"header":[{"items":[{"align":"left"},{"align":"left"}]}]}

This seems to work, but I need for it to by dynamic.

```
var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"header":[{"items":[{"align":""},{"align":""}]}]}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `align` is the same Object, both the items point to the same reference when you set the `property` align they get overwritten..

```
jObj["header"][0].items.push(align);
jObj["header"][0].items.push({...align});
```

Comment: So, I was pointing to the same object referenced twice and this enables it to create a new object. Seems to work.

Comment: I've never seen this before what is this notation called?

Comment: This called a `spread` operator, will create a shallow copy...

Comment: Of Course this method doesn't work in IE, don't know why anyone has to support it.

Comment: function spreadify (item) {
        var clone ={};
        for( var key in item ){
            if(item.hasOwnProperty(key)) //ensure not adding inherited props
                clone[key]=item[key];
        }
        return clone;
    };

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing a reference... Any change in one is reflected in the other. Try [Object.assign({}, align)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead. It will create a copy without reference of the object.

```js
var jObj = {
    "header": [{        
        "items": []
    }]
}

var align = {"align": ""};
jObj["header"][0].items.push(Object.assign({}, align));
jObj["header"][0].items.push(Object.assign({}, align));

jObj["header"][0].items[0].align = "right";
jObj["header"][0].items[1].align = "left";

console.log(jObj);
```

PD: Js treats json as array so there is no need of parsing.